# Losing timezone on data retrieval over objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone

I have a model which has a `DateTimeField` for a start date as timestamp. When I'm creating new objects of the model and store them in the PostgreSQL database the given timezone is `Europe/Berlin`.

I confirmed it just before calling `save()` and the entries have the correct offsets in the database. The timezone of the database also matches with the timezone of the objects.

But when I retrieve objects of the model over `.filter()` the timezone is set to `UTC`, so I'm losing the timezone. Of course it should be `Europe/Berlin` as well. Inside `settings.py` is also the correct timezone:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If I set USE_TZ = False, I get the right time. So it seems like django internally converts the start date to UTC after or on retrieval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following post provides an answer to the question:

[return datetimes in the active timezone with a django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247854/return-datetimes-in-the-active-timezone-with-a-django-query)

The answer of this post states that Django will always return UTC, so one has to normalize the date after the queries. Case closed.