# Django timezone struggles

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I am having difficulty getting queryset results in my own timezone. 
for example:
model field definition:

```
some_datetime_field= models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Query:

```
MyModel.values_list("some_datetime_field",flat=True).first()
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 5, 14, 56, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

instead of returning

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 5, 6, 56, 16, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

I am working with python V3.7.5, Django V2.2.7 and **PostgreSQL V12** as my database. 
In my setting I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = "America/Los_Angeles"
USE_TZ = True
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

From the documentation it says with regard to the "TIME_ZONE" settings: [(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#time-zone)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#time-zone)

> When USE_TZ is True and the database supports time zones (e.g. PostgreSQL), it is an error to set this option.

so I tried to remove the TIME_ZONE from my setting:

```
USE_TZ = True
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

but that didnt work either, even worse, when I try to localize it with `timezone.localtime(datetime_example)` i get the time in Chicago time:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 5, 8, 56, 16, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>)
```

**How can I get my query set to return DateTime in my chosen timezone instead of UTC?**

Comment: Keep `TIME_ZONE` (ignore the warning) and then check `timezone.localtime`.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but the queryset doesn't return the local timezone (as you can see in the first portion of the question with the TIME_ZONE setting). it only returns UTC.

Comment: It's saved and retrieved as UTC. You need to do the necessary conversions yourself.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247854/return-datetimes-in-the-active-timezone-with-a-django-query. There is explanation for the similar case.

Comment: Thank you @IvanMarkeev that was super helpful. I was looking for such a solution for a while. thank you for pointing this out.